# How to add a column of fitted values to a data frame by group?

Tags: r, error-handling, dplyr, regression, quantreg

Say I have a data frame like this:

```
X <- data_frame(
  x = rep(seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1), 3),
  y = 2*x + rnorm(length(x), sd = 0.5),
  g = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = length(x)/3))
```

How can I fit a regression `y~x` grouped by variable `g` and add the values from the `fitted` and `resid` generic methods to the data frame?

I know I can do:

```
A <- X[X$g == "A",]
mA <- with(A, lm(y ~ x))
A$fit <- fitted(mA)
A$res <- resid(mA)

B <- X[X$g == "B",]
mB <- with(B, lm(y ~ x))
B$fit <- fitted(mB)
B$res <- resid(mB)

C <- X[X$g == "C",]
mC <- with(B, lm(y ~ x))
C$fit <- fitted(mC)
C$res <- resid(mC)
```

And then `rbind(A, B, C)`. However, in real life I am not using `lm` (I'm using `rqss` in the `quantreg` package). The method occasionally fails, so I need error handling, where I'd like to place `NA` all the rows that failed. Also, there are way more than 3 groups, so I don't want to just keep copying and pasting code for each group.

I tried using `dplyr` with `do` but didn't make any progress. I was thinking it might be something like:

```
make_qfits <- function(data) {
  data %>%
    group_by(g) %>%
    do(failwith(NULL, rqss), formula = y ~ qss(x, lambda = 3))
}
```

Would this be easy to do by that approach? Is there another way in base R?

Comment: The `augment.columns` function from package **broom** comes to mind.  What did you try in `do` that wasn't working?

Comment: @aosmith I was thinking it might be something like the code I just added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `lm` models you could try

```
library(nlme)     # lmList to do lm by group
library(ggplot2)  # fortify to get out the fitted/resid data
do.call(rbind, lapply(lmList(y ~ x | g, data=X), fortify))
```

This gives you the residual and fitted data in ".resid" and ".fitted" columns as well as a bunch of other fit data.  By default the rownames will be prefixed with the letters from `g`.

With the `rqss` models that might fail

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(X, X$g), function(z) {
    fit <- tryCatch({
        rqss(y ~ x, data=z)
    }, error=function(e) NULL)
    if (is.null(fit)) data.frame(resid=numeric(0), fitted=numeric(0))
    else data.frame(resid=fit$resid, fitted=fitted(fit))
}))
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't that force me to use `lme` behind the scenes? I'm trying to make non-parametric fits with `rqss` since my real data is nonlinear.

Comment: @wdkrnls ok, the `fortify` wasn't working with `rqss` so I added a split-apply-combine solution

Comment: @nongkrog Thanks! That looks like something I can work with. But the fit occasionally fails with `idObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class "matrix.csr" object: ra and ja don't have equal lengths`. How would you do error handling if `rqss` fails?

Comment: @wdkrnls i would add in a `tryCatch` clause, try the edit, I don't have failing data so Im not sure

Comment: Hmm, I tried binding the columns together and saw that the number of rows were different. `bind_cols(X, Y)`
> Error: incompatible number of rows (20553, expecting 21561)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `do` on grouped data for this task, fitting the model in each group in `do` and putting the model residuals and fitted values into a `data.frame`.  To add these to the original data, just include the `.` that represents the data going into `do` in the output `data.frame`.

In your simple case, this would look like this:

```
X %>%
    group_by(g) %>%
    do({model = rqss(y ~ qss(x, lambda = 3), data = .)
        data.frame(., residuals = resid.rqss(model), fitted = fitted(model))
            })

Source: local data frame [30 x 5]
Groups: g

    x         y g     residuals    fitted
1   1  1.509760 A -1.368963e-08  1.509760
2   2  3.576973 A -8.915993e-02  3.666133
3   3  6.239950 A  4.174453e-01  5.822505
4   4  7.978878 A  4.130033e-09  7.978878
5   5 10.588367 A  4.833475e-01 10.105020
6   6 11.786445 A -3.807876e-01 12.167232
7   7 14.646221 A  4.167763e-01 14.229445
8   8 15.938253 A -3.534045e-01 16.291658
9   9 19.114927 A  7.610560e-01 18.353871
10 10 19.574449 A -8.416343e-01 20.416083
.. ..       ... .           ...       ...
```

Things will look more complicated if you need to catch errors.  Here is what it would look like using `try` and filling the residuals and fitted columns with `NA` if fit attempt for the group results in an error.

```
X[9:30,] %>%
    group_by(g) %>%
    do({catch = try(rqss(y ~ qss(x, lambda = 3), data = .))
    if(class(catch) == "try-error"){
        data.frame(., residuals = NA, fitted = NA)
    }
    else{
        model = rqss(y ~ qss(x, lambda = 3), data = .)
        data.frame(., residuals = resid.rqss(model), fitted = fitted(model))
        }
    })
Source: local data frame [22 x 5]
Groups: g

    x         y g     residuals    fitted
1   9 19.114927 A            NA        NA
2  10 19.574449 A            NA        NA
3   1  2.026199 B -4.618675e-01  2.488066
4   2  4.399768 B  1.520739e-11  4.399768
5   3  6.167690 B -1.437800e-01  6.311470
6   4  8.642481 B  4.193089e-01  8.223172
7   5 10.255790 B  1.209160e-01 10.134874
8   6 12.875674 B  8.290981e-01 12.046576
9   7 13.958278 B -4.803891e-10 13.958278
10  8 15.691032 B -1.789479e-01 15.869980
.. ..       ... .           ...       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that works with base R:

```
modelit <- function(df) {
    mB <- with(df, lm(y ~ x, na.action = na.exclude))
    df$fit <- fitted(mB)
    df$res <- resid(mB)
    return(df)
}

dfs.with.preds <- lapply(split(X, as.factor(X$g)), modelit)
output <- Reduce(function(x, y) { rbind(x, y) }, dfs.with.preds)
```