# Add Column of Predicted Values to Data Frame with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with a column of models and I am trying to add a column of predicted values to it. A minimal example is :

```
exampleTable <- data.frame(x = c(1:5, 1:5),
                           y = c((1:5) + rnorm(5), 2*(5:1)),
                           groups = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 5))
                           
models <- exampleTable %>% group_by(groups) %>% do(model = lm(y ~ x, data = .))
exampleTable <- left_join(tbl_df(exampleTable), models)

estimates <- exampleTable %>% rowwise() %>% do(Est = predict(.$model, newdata = .["x"]))
```

How can I add a column of numeric predictions to `exampleTable`? I tried using `mutate` to directly add the column to the table without success.

```
exampleTable <- exampleTable %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(data.frame(Pred = predict(.$model, newdata = .["x"])))
```

> Error: no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "list"

Now I use `bind_cols` to add the `estimates` to `exampleTable` but I am looking for a better solution.

```
estimates <- exampleTable %>% rowwise() %>% do(data.frame(Pred = predict(.$model, newdata = .["x"])))
exampleTable <- bind_cols(exampleTable, estimates)
```

How can it be done in a single step?

Comment: You can do the model fitting and get the predicted values in one `do` step.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29142831/2461552) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31753571/2461552).  In your case it would look something like: `exampleTable %>% group_by(groups) %>%  do({ model = lm(y ~ x, data = .);
 data.frame(., estimates = predict(model))})` (but usually with a line break instead of a semicolon).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using modelr, there is an elegant solution using the tidyverse.

**The inputs**

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

# generate the inputs like in the question
example_table <- data.frame(x = c(1:5, 1:5),
                            y = c((1:5) + rnorm(5), 2*(5:1)),
                            groups = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 5))

models <- example_table %>% 
  group_by(groups) %>% 
  do(model = lm(y ~ x, data = .)) %>%
  ungroup()
example_table <- left_join(tbl_df(example_table ), models, by = "groups")
```

**The solution**

```
# generate the extra column
example_table %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  do(modelr::add_predictions(., first(.$model)))
```

**The explanation**

`add_predictions` adds a new column to a data frame using a given model. Unfortunately it only takes one model as an argument. Meet `do`. Using do, we can run `add_prediction` individually over each group.

`.` represents the grouped data frame, `.$model` the model column and `first()` takes the first model of each group.

**Simplified**

With only one model, add_predictions works very well.

```
# take one of the models
model <- example_table$model[[6]]

# generate the extra column
example_table %>%
  modelr::add_predictions(model)
```

**Recipes**

Nowadays, the tidyverse is shifting from the `modelr` package to `recipes` so that might be the new way to go once this package matures.

Answer (score 9):

Using the tidyverse:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)

exampleTable <- data.frame(
  x = c(1:5, 1:5),
  y = c((1:5) + rnorm(5), 2*(5:1)),
  groups = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 5)
)

exampleTable %>% 
  group_by(groups) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(model = data %>% map(~lm(y ~ x, data = .))) %>% 
  mutate(Pred = map2(model, data, predict)) %>% 
  unnest(Pred, data)

# A tibble: 10 × 4
   groups      Pred     x          y
   <fctr>     <dbl> <int>      <dbl>
1       A  1.284185     1  0.9305908
2       A  1.909262     2  1.9598293
3       A  2.534339     3  3.2812002
4       A  3.159415     4  2.9283637
5       A  3.784492     5  3.5717085
6       B 10.000000     1 10.0000000
7       B  8.000000     2  8.0000000
8       B  6.000000     3  6.0000000
9       B  4.000000     4  4.0000000
10      B  2.000000     5  2.0000000
```

Comment: You can define `model` and `Pred` in one `mutate`

Answer (score 1):

Eh, this is only slightly better:

```
answer = 
  exampleTable %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  do(lm( y ~ x , data = .) %>% 
       predict %>% 
       data_frame(prediction = .)) %>%
  bind_cols(exampleTable)
```

I was hoping this would work but it didn't.

```
answer = 
  exampleTable %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  mutate(prediction = 
           lm( y ~ x , data = .) %>% 
           predict)
```