# How to use predict in R with 500 regressions stored as a list

Tags: r, list, loops, rstudio, regression

I am trying to use the predict function on a list that contains 500 regression models.

Here is how far I have got:

```
lapply(reg_results, function(model) {predict(model, newdata=subset(df,key==1))})
```

However, it is not working :(.

Thank you,

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: are you trying to calculate predictions for each of the 500 models? If so, try this answer which relies on the purrr package: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44709870/using-lm-in-list-column-to-predict-new-values-using-purrr)

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I figured it out by trial and error, was driving me crazy, here is what worked:


`lapply(reg_results, function(model) {predict(model,newdata=subset(df, date=="12/15/2016 12:00:00 AM" & key=="1"))})`