# Add predicted values for multiple different models to a novel dataset by groups

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by

Given a data.frame of grouped data:

```
library(tidyverse)

# fake up some grouped data: 
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), 
                  y = rnorm(100), 
                  group = rep(x=letters[1:10],each=10))
head(dat)
> head(dat)
            x           y group
1 -0.56047565 -0.71040656     a
2 -0.23017749  0.25688371     a
3  1.55870831 -0.24669188     a
4  0.07050839 -0.34754260     a
5  0.12928774 -0.95161857     a
6  1.71506499 -0.04502772     a
```

I want to build a set of independent models by one (or more) grouping columns:

```
# store models by group in a list
models <- list()
for(i in letters[1:10]) {
  models[[paste0("mdl_",i)]] = lm(y ~ x, dat %>% filter(group == i))
}

names(models)
 [1] "mdl_a" "mdl_b" "mdl_c" "mdl_d" "mdl_e" "mdl_f" "mdl_g" "mdl_h" "mdl_i" "mdl_j"
```

I can add the model predictions (fitted values) to the original data frame a number of ways, this way is convenient:

```
# add model predictions (fitted values) column to original data frame
dat <- dat %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(fits = lm(y ~ x)$fitted.values)

# verify prediction from stored models and fitted values column match 
# to within a 10-decimal tolerance: 
for(i in letters[1:10]) {
  tmp <- dat %>%
    filter(group == i) %>%
    select(group, x, y, fits)
  tmp$stored_fit = predict(models[[paste0("mdl_",i)]], tmp)
  print(paste("mdl", i, "results match:", all(round(tmp$stored_fit,10) == round(tmp$fits,10))))
}
[1] "mdl a results match: TRUE"
[1] "mdl b results match: TRUE"
[1] "mdl c results match: TRUE"
[1] "mdl d results match: TRUE"
[1] "mdl e results match: TRUE"
[1] "mdl f results match: TRUE"
[1] "mdl g results match: TRUE"
[1] "mdl h results match: TRUE"
[1] "mdl i results match: TRUE"
[1] "mdl j results match: TRUE"
```

All of these steps have been discused in other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773617/add-column-of-predicted-values-to-data-frame-with-dplyr).

Now I want to generate the predictions from these models on a new data.frame and add those predictions as a column to that data.frame.

Here's a couple things I tried:

```
# fake up some new grouped data: 
set.seed(456)
dat2 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), 
                   y = rnorm(100), 
                   group = rep(x=letters[1:10],each=10))
```

### Method 1 (apply):

```
tmp <- dat2 %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  nest() # %>%
  # mutate(fits = map())

fits = as.data.frame(apply(X = tmp, MARGIN=1, FUN = function(X) predict(models[[paste0("mdl_",X$group)]], X$data)))
names(fits) = tmp$group
fits <- fits %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "group.fits") %>% 
  arrange(group.fits)

tmp <- tmp %>%
  unnest(cols = c(data)) %>%
  bind_cols(fits)
```

... which just feels error-prone and inelegant.

### Method 2 (for loop, base r):

```
tmp$fits = NA
for(g in unique(tmp$group)) {
  tmp[tmp$group==g,]$fits = predict(models[[paste0("mdl_",g)]], tmp[tmp$group==g,])
}
tmp
```

Nothing particularly wrong with this other than for loops being notoriously slow on larger datasets.

### Method 3 (nest/map):

I thought something like the following would work but I have something wrong in the syntax...

```
dat2 %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(fits = map(.f = predict(models[[paste0("mdl_",group)]]), data))
```

or

```
  mutate(fits = map(.x = data, 
                    .f = predict(models[[paste0("mdl_",group)]],
                                 .x)))
```

I'm looking for an answer somewhere along Method 3's route - ideally all within one set of dplyr commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Option 1: `purrr::map2`

To walk along your method 3, you should use `map2()` to predict across each model and data.

```r
dat2 %>%
  nest(.by = group) %>% # .by: {tidyr} >= v1.3.0
  mutate(fits = map2(group, data, ~ predict(models[[paste0("mdl_", .x)]], .y))) %>%
  unnest(c(data, fits))
```

---

##### Option 2: `rowwise`

You can also substitute `rowwise()` for `map2()` and surround the predicted values with `list()`.

```r
dat2 %>%
  nest(.by = group) %>% # .by: {tidyr} >= v1.3.0
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(fits = list(predict(models[[paste0("mdl_", group)]], data))) %>%
  unnest(c(data, fits))
```

---

##### Option 3: `group_modify`

You even do not need `nest`/`unnest` from `{tidyr}`. Just take advantage of  `dplyr::group_modify()`:

```r
dat2 %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  group_modify(~ {
    .x %>% mutate(fits = predict(models[[paste0("mdl_", .y$group)]], .x))
  }) %>%
  ungroup()
```

---

All approaches return the same output:

```
# # A tibble: 100 × 4
#    group      x       y   fits
#    <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1 a     -1.34   0.118  -0.677
#  2 a      0.622  0.870  -0.287
#  3 a      0.801 -0.0919 -0.252
#  4 a     -1.39   0.0689 -0.686
#  5 a     -0.714 -1.68   -0.552
#  6 a     -0.324  1.12   -0.475
#  7 a      0.691 -1.35   -0.274
#  8 a      0.251 -0.537  -0.361
#  9 a      1.01  -0.370  -0.211
# 10 a      0.573  0.354  -0.297
# # ℹ 90 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

---

##### Benchmark

```r
bench::mark(
  `purrr::map2` = {
    dat2 %>%
      nest(.by = group) %>%
      mutate(fits = map2(group, data, ~ predict(models[[paste0("mdl_", .x)]], .y))) %>%
      unnest(c(data, fits))
  }, `dplyr::rowwise` = {
    dat2 %>%
      nest(.by = group) %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(fits = list(predict(models[[paste0("mdl_", group)]], data))) %>%
      unnest(c(data, fits))
  }, `dplyr::group_modify` = {
    dat2 %>%
      group_by(group) %>%
      group_modify(~ {
        .x %>% mutate(fits = predict(models[[paste0("mdl_", .y$group)]], .x))
      }) %>%
      ungroup()
  },
  iterations = 100, min_time = Inf
)

# # A tibble: 3 × 13
#   expression            min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#   <bch:expr>         <bch:> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
# 1 purrr::map2        16.7ms 17.3ms      57.0    36.4KB     3.00    95     5      1.67s
# 2 dplyr::rowwise     19.9ms 20.2ms      48.7    40.7KB     3.11    94     6      1.93s
# 3 dplyr::group_modi… 33.1ms 34.3ms      28.8     186KB     3.20    90    10      3.13s
```

Comment: I have always found rowwise to be extremely slow.

Comment: that said, group_modify looks interesting... I was unaware of that.

Comment: @BrianD I update a new method using `map2` to my answer. `rowwise` is slow for the case where row number is very large. In this case, you have nested rows of each group into a list-column of data frames, so the number of rows reduces to that of groups. `rowwise` does not take too much time. Please see the benchmark part. Both `map2` and `rowwise` perform well than `group_modify`.

Comment: with `map2` I'm getting an error that 'group' is not found.

Answer (score 1):

For dplyr 1.0.9, purrr 0.3.4:

```
 dat2 %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  nest() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(fits = map2(.x = group, 
                     .y = data, 
                     ~ predict(models[[paste0("mdl_", .x)]], .y))) %>%
  unnest(c(data, fits))
```

OR

```
dat2 %>%
  nest_by(group) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(fits = list(predict(models[[paste0("mdl_", group)]], data))) %>%
  unnest(c(data, fits))
```

Comment: For the first code, using `map2` on a grouped data is redundant. You can move `ungroup` to behind `nest()`. That will improve some efficiency.

Comment: not sure what you mean by redundant, it works perfectly.

Comment: You could check the edit that I move forward `ungroup()`. You can use `bench::mark()` to compare both versions before and after moving `ungroup`. The new one takes much less time in my computer.